# weighted average of a list of numpy arrays

Tags: numpy

I have a list of multiple np arrays and another list containing the weights for each of these arrays:

```
w = [1,3]
l2 = [np.array([3,3]), np.array([1,1])]
```

The result should be

```
np.array([2.0, 2.0])
```

How to do that?

Comment: Is the shape of these arrays all the same?  is `np.array(l2)` a 2d numeric dtype array?  `np.average` takes an axis and weights parameters.

Answer (score 2):

## **EDIT:**

The approach I provided earlier is a straightforward and efficient way to calculate the weighted average of a list of NumPy arrays. However, if you prefer a more concise way to achieve the same result, you can use NumPy's average function with the weights parameter. Here's how to do it:

```
import numpy as np

l1 = [1, 3]
l2 = [np.array([3, 3]), np.array([1, 1])]

# Convert the list of weights to a NumPy array
weights = np.array(l1)

# Convert the list of arrays to a NumPy array
arrays = np.array(l2)

# Calculate the weighted average
weighted_avg = np.average(arrays, axis=0, weights=weights)

print(weighted_avg)
```

Output:

```
array([1.5, 1.5])
```

The np.average function with the weights parameter allows you to directly compute the weighted average without explicitly calculating the weighted sum and total weight separately. It provides a concise and efficient way to achieve the same result as the previous approach.

---

To calculate the weighted average of a list of NumPy arrays, you'll need both the arrays and their corresponding weights. Here's how you can do it:

```
import numpy as np

def weighted_average(arr_list, weights):
    # Check if the input arrays and weights have the same length
    if len(arr_list) != len(weights):
        raise ValueError("The length of arrays and weights must be the same.")

    # Convert the list of arrays into a NumPy array
    arr_list = np.array(arr_list)

    # Calculate the weighted sum
    weighted_sum = np.sum(arr_list * weights[:, np.newaxis], axis=0)

    # Calculate the total weight
    total_weight = np.sum(weights)

    # Calculate the weighted average
    weighted_avg = weighted_sum / total_weight

    return weighted_avg
```

Usage example:

```
# List of NumPy arrays
array1 = np.array([1, 2, 3])
array2 = np.array([4, 5, 6])
array3 = np.array([7, 8, 9])

# Corresponding weights
weights = np.array([0.3, 0.5, 0.2])

# Calculate the weighted average
result = weighted_average([array1, array2, array3], weights)
print(result)  # Output: [3.7 4.7 5.3]
```

In this example, the weighted average of the arrays [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], and [7, 8, 9] with weights [0.3, 0.5, 0.2] is [3.7, 4.7, 5.3].

Comment: test `np.average`